# webservice-Async call

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-phone-7

I have a webservice running and one of its method does not return immediately when called. It returns when it has data. Once it returns, the client again calls it so that client will be provided with the data whenever service has data. This is to avoid polling. But the problem is ,it works fine in emulator whereas in device though the webservie does not return, client ends up in th below function resuling in null exception.

```
public string Endgetstatus(System.IAsyncResult result) 
{
    object[] _args = new object[0];
    string _result = ((string)(base.EndInvoke("getstatus", _args, result)));
    return _result;
}
```

This is how i call async function which returns when it has data otherwise it won't return.

```
client.getstatusCompleted += new EventHandler<getstatusCompletedEventArgs>(updatereceived);

client.getstatusAsync();//this returns only when it has data
```

Does device terminates any open connection after certain period of time and forcing client to call the Endgetstatus function? I have set the timeout to 23 hours

```
BasicHttpBinding binding= new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding();
TimeSpan interval = new TimeSpan(23, 14, 18);
binding.ReceiveTimeout = interval;
binding.SendTimeout = interval;
```

After one minute client ends up in

```
public string Endgetstatus(System.IAsyncResult result) {
```

resulting in argument null exception though the webservice does not return.

Can anyone let me know what I should do to make in work on the device as it works fine on emulator?

Please note that this about windows phone 7 and silverlight c#

Answer (score 0):

I believe the WebClient will timeout, by default, after 1 minute.
Is the difference between the emulator and device behaviour just the platform or are you doing/timing things differently.

Yoy may want to consider Raw toast notifications to let your application know that there is some new data to request as this does not require polling from the device.

Comment: There is no difference in behaviour between emulator and device. I initially used  push notification but it is very unstable and using that i can not qurantte that my solution will work. Thats the reason i moved to this architecture that client will call a method in webservice and it returns only when it has data.

Comment: @user641247 have you tried running a network trace or similar (maybe with Fiddler or WireShark) to look for differences there?